# A more elegant proof that affine morphisms of schemes are affine local on the target

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, schemes, affine-schemes

To being with, I am using the following definition for an affine morphism of schemes.

> A morphism $f: X \longrightarrow Y$ is said to be affine if there exists a cover $\{ \text{Spec }A_{i}  \}$ of $Y$ by affines such that each $f^{-1}(\text{Spec }A_{i})$ is affine in $X$.

It is a well known result that if $f: X \longrightarrow Y$ is an affine morphism of schemes, then for any affine open set $\text{Spec }B \subseteq Y$, the preimage is affine. I am having a little trouble understanding the proof of this.

Without loss of generality, we may assume that $Y = \text{Spec }B$ is affine. Suppose $\{ g_{1}, g_{2}, \ldots , g_{m}  \}$ generates the unit ideal in $B$, and suppose that $f^{-1}(D(g_{i})) = \text{Spec }A_{i}$ is affine in $X$. The part of the proof I am stuck on is showing that $X$ must then be affine. I have something of a proof, but I have been told this is not a good way to prove it, and that I am "missing the point" of the exercise. The standard procedure seems to be to use the following result

> A scheme $X$ is affine if and only if there is a collection $\{ g_{1}, g_{2}, \ldots  , g_{m}\}$ generating the unit ideal in $\Gamma(X, \mathcal{O}_{X})$, and the open sets $X_{g_{i}}$ are affine, where $X_{g_{i}}$ is the set of all points $p \in X$ such that the germ of $g_{i}$ at $p$ is not contained in the maximal ideal of the local ring $\mathcal{O}_{X, p}$.

With my situation as above, I have the morphism $f: X \longrightarrow \text{Spec }B$, which corresponds to a morphism of rings
$$
\psi: B \longrightarrow \Gamma(X, \mathcal{O}_{X}),
$$
and the $\psi(g_{i})$ generate the unit ideal in $\Gamma(X, \mathcal{O}_{X})$. My problem is that I can't see how to show that $X_{\psi(g_{i})}$ is affine in $X$. I'm expecting that the $X_{\psi(g_{i})}$ should be equal to the $\text{Spec }A_{i}$ but I can't see a nice way to show this.

I was also wondering if someone knows of a reference that doesn't do this in the language of $\mathcal{O}_{\text{Spec }B}$-algebras?

Comment: I might be missing something here, but isn't $X_{\psi(g_i)} = f^{-1}(D(g_i))$ more or less tautologically? And $f^{-1}(D(g_i)) = \operatorname{Spec} A_i$ is affine.

Comment: @ZachTeitler Ideally I would like that to be true (and I believe it is true), but it doesn't seem tautological to me. It would certainly be tautological in the case that $X$ was affine, but that would be begging the question. Or is there something fundamental I'm missing that makes it obvious in the non-affine case?

Comment: Well just on the level of points, for a point $x \in X$, $x \in f^{-1}(D(g_i))$ if and only if $f(x) \in D(g_i)$, if and only if $g_i \notin \mathfrak{m}_{f(x)}$, if and only if $\psi(g_i) \notin \mathfrak{m}_x$ (since the map on stalks is a map of local rings), if and only if $x \in X_{\psi(g_i)}$... better not take my word for it, better check. I'm probably wrong about maps of local rings, I always get that stuff messed up :(